# Will a WCF-client ignore the URL scheme in the endpoint address (HTTPS) if binding security is set to NONE

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

A WCF-client is configured with an endpoint address that specifies HTTP**S**-scheme, but its **basicHttpBinding**'s **Security** is set to NONE. Will it ignore the scheme in the endpoint address and send requests over plain HTTP anyway?

Comment: It depends on whether your client is using http or https.

Comment: @DingPeng How can I check that? Is it a config setting?

Comment: You can check whether the client is using https or http in the endpoint node in App.config.